# DeleteAsync() broke my app

Tags: windows, asynchronous, win-universal-app, delete-file

I've been playing around with DeleteAsync() to try and delete a folder called 'Images' inside Assets. I then want to recreate the folder so that it now contains no files.

My folder never deleted, its still in Assets with all its files, but when I re-run the app after the code below it crashes at             `StorageFolder appFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path1);`

My guess is that I misunderstood DeleteAsync() and removed some form of reference to the path without actually deleting the folder.

If I delete the 'Images' folder in the VS2015 Solution Explorer, then recreate it manually and add back in all the files manually, the app will run fine again.

Could someone help explain whats going on and if its possible to physically delete a known folder?

```
 //Get the folder location.
            string root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
            string path1 = root + @"\Assets";
            string path2 = path1 + @"\Images";
            StorageFolder appFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path1);
            StorageFolder appFolder1 = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path2);

            //Delete a folder.
            if (await appFolder.TryGetItemAsync(@"\Images") != null)
            {
                await appFolder1.DeleteAsync();
                await appFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Images");
            }
```

Comment: I remove "\" in your code line `if (await appFolder.TryGetItemAsync(@"\Images") != null)`, it works.

Comment: I suspect you're not supposed to delete files from your own app package. You can delete files from your local settings folder, but the InstalledLocation is read-only.

Comment: Thanks @Jayden Gu, I tried that but my files are still there when the app closes. Do files I create in the local app data store get deleted automatically when the app closes? I've created and read a sample text file from code in debug mode, but cant find it after closing the app. Basically I just want to download files from azure, use them, then delete them and download new files for use. Having trouble getting my head around the transition from Win Forms to Win Universal. This is deploying onto a dedicated ARM machine, so I dont have capacity concerns as if deploying on a phone.

Comment: It seems you want download the files, read them, then delete. You can use `LocalFolder`, same with the Raymond Chen said  the InstalledLocation is read-only. And it has clear method [ApplicationData.ClearAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.clearasync.aspx)